# How to detect user email address when user clicks on a link sent to their email?

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am sending links to user email using System.Net.Mail in MVC which redirect user to a page in my app when they click on it.
For security reason, I need to prevent users from sharing that sensitive link. So I encrypt the url parameters before sending to prevent from sharing. but it's not enough because user can forward the email to others. So if they forward the email to another person, I'd like to compare the email address saved in my app with the one where the link has been clicked and find out whether the link has been clicked by original user.

I allow user to connect via multiple devices so IP checking doesn't help this.
Is there any way to detect user email address when user clicks on a link?

Comment: Is the link a one-time-link or can it be used several times?

Comment: Tack the email id on the sent URL as a request parameter?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. You can disable the link once it's clicked once, though.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano at the moment i allow it to be used several time but i set a timestamp as parameter for the link. so when it expires i disregard call from the link.

Comment: @Blorgbeard even if i make it one-time-click link they still can forward it without clicking on it.

Comment: Yes, and there's nothing you can do about that. Email clients don't send out their email address when a user clicks a link. The user could also just copy and paste it into a web browser. And the web browser doesn't even know it came from an email.